# Mouse Over popup similar to Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, popup

I searched a  lot for a  mouse over pop up similar to face book,but couldn't find .

I am searching for not just a tool tip.If you notice facebook  mouse over pop up.You can do a lot of operations like 'add friend' in that pop up.In normal tool tip, we can't even move the mouse to that pop up.I am searching for such a pop up like face book doing

Can any one  give a hint for such a pop up.

Answer (score 1):

search for `jQuery tooltip` , there are thousands of them.

check this for reference

[Experimental jQuery Tooltips](http://papermashup.com/experimental-jquery-tooltips/)

Comment: thanks for the response.But I am not asking for just a tool tip.If you notice facebook  mouse over pop up.You can do a lot of operations like 'add friend'....In tool tip, we can't even move the mouse to that pop up.I am searching for such a popup